# How to increase space between cells or rows of Xamarin forms list view for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms project and I've used list view in it. I'm trying to add space between two cells of a list. I've used renderer for that and successfully accomplished it in android. I'm using same approach on iOS but not getting any solution. Also my cells have borders of width 1. So it is not possible to embed one more blank view at bottom of cell in iOS. This is how I've provided border of width two list cell in my custom ViewCell renderer.

`UITableViewCell cell =    base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);
 cell.ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
 cell.ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex ("BFE0E0E0").ToCGColor ();
 cell.ContentView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;`

Please suggest me any way through which I can accomplish spacing between two cells of a list.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with [collections](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/) and not with tables. In the following layout-example you can set vertical and horizontal spacing:

```
var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize(0, 0),
    FooterReferenceSize = new CGSize(0, 0),
    SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
    ItemSize = new CGSize(cellwidth, cellheight),
    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
    MinimumInteritemSpacing = verticalspacing,
    MinimumLineSpacing = horizontalspacing
};

var mycollection = new UICollectionView(CGRect.Empty, layout);;
```

Then you just need to set the source of your `UiCollectionView` to your list of items. In this source you can define the layout/design of a single item in your colleciton (just like a `UITableViewCell`).

Comment: @Joeshi There's no UICollectionView in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Oh.. sorry.. My bad. Just look at this: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/65220/#Comment_65220 maybe that can help you out. We used this XLabs library in several projects